# Neo4j - too slow writing speed for importing log files in real-time?

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I'm trying to find out if network traffic log files can be analyzed with Neo4j. 
Therefore, I am "tailing" 3 different log files from Bro IDS in real-time using "sh"-library and importing the log records into neo4j which seems to be very slow using py2neo. A CSV import won't work here, since it is real-time.

An example: I am analyzing a one-hour packet capture file using tcpreplay that has almost 4.000.000 connections. I even played it with half of the tempo. So after 2 hrs I had about 4.000.000 log entries.Right now, 3,5hrs after beginning of the analysis, I have just imported 289691 graphs consisting of 5 nodes and 4 relationships. All in all, about 15% of the data in almost double the time.

I am using py2neo and the code looks like following (this is one of the graphs):

```
def create_conn_graph(connlog):
[...]

##  Start Session
graph = Graph(bolt=True, password="neo4j")
tx = graph.begin()

############
##  Nodes ##
############

##  Connection Node
conn = Node("Connection", uid=connlog['uid'],
            ts=connlog['ts'],
            date=evt_date,
            time=evt_time,
            [...])

conn_properties = dict(conn)
for key in conn_properties.keys():
    if conn[key] == "-" or conn[key] == "(empty)":
        conn[key] = "0"
conn.update()
tx.merge(conn, "Connection", "uid")

##  IP Nodes
orig = Node("IP", ip=connlog['orig_h'])
tx.merge(orig)

resp = Node("IP", ip=connlog['resp_h'])
tx.merge(resp)

##  History Node
if connlog['history']:
    hist_flow = history_flow(connlog['history'])
    history_node = Node("History", history=connlog['history'], flow=hist_flow)
    tx.merge(history_node, "History", "history")

    ##  (Connection)-[HAS_HISTORY]->(History)
    conn_hist = Relationship(conn, "HAS_HISTORY", history_node)
    tx.merge(conn_hist)

##  Conn_State
conn_state = Node("Conn_State", state=connlog['conn_state'], meaning=CONN_STATE[connlog['conn_state']])
tx.merge(conn_state, "Conn_State", "conn_state")

tx.commit()
tx = graph.begin()

#####################
##  Relationships  ##
#####################

##  (IP)-[STARTS_CONNECTION]->(Connection)
orig_conn = Relationship(orig, "STARTS_CONNECTION", conn, port=connlog['orig_p'])
tx.merge(orig_conn)

##  (Connection)-[CONNECTS_TO]->(IP)
conn_resp = Relationship(conn, "CONNECTS_TO", resp, port=connlog['resp_p'])
tx.merge(conn_resp)

##  (Connection)-[HAS_CONN_STATE]->(Conn_State)
conn_connstate = Relationship(conn, "HAS_CONN_STATE", conn_state)
tx.merge(conn_connstate)

tx.commit()
## (Connection)-[PRODUCED]-> (DNS|HTTP)
if connlog['service'] == "dns":
    graph.run("MATCH (c:Connection {uid:{uid}}), (d:DNS {uid:{uid}}) \
        MERGE (c)-[:PRODUCED]->(d)",
              {"uid": connlog['uid']})

if connlog['service'] == "http":
    graph.run("MATCH (c:Connection {uid:{uid}}), (d:HTTP {uid:{uid}}) \
        MERGE (c)-[:PRODUCED]->(d)",
              {"uid": connlog['uid']})

return True


##  End of create_conn_graph    ########################################


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logentry = {}
    logfield = CONNLOG
    logline = []

    for line in tail("-F", LOG_DIR, _iter=True, _bg=True):
        entry = line.strip().split("\t")
        if line.startswith('#'):
            continue
        for i in range(len(logfield)):
            logentry[logfield[i]] = entry[i]
        create_conn_graph(logentry)
```

I have the following constraints and indexes:

```
graph.run("CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:Connection) ASSERT c.uid IS UNIQUE")
graph.run("CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (i:IP) ASSERT i.ip IS UNIQUE")
graph.run("CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:Conn_State) ASSERT c.conn_state IS UNIQUE")
graph.run("CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (h:History) ASSERT h.history IS UNIQUE")
graph.run("CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (host:Host) ASSERT host.host is UNIQUE")
graph.run("CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (q:QueryType) ASSERT q.type is UNIQUE")
graph.run("CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (qc:QueryClass) ASSERT qc.class is UNIQUE")
graph.run("CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (rc:ResponseCode) ASSERT rc.code is UNIQUE")
graph.run("CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (ic:InfoCode) ASSERT ic.code is UNIQUE")
graph.run("CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (ua:UserAgent) ASSERT ua.useragent is UNIQUE")
graph.run("CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (m:Method) ASSERT m.method is UNIQUE")
graph.run("CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (r:Referrer) ASSERT r.referrer is UNIQUE")
graph.run("CREATE INDEX ON :DNS(uid)")
graph.run("CREATE INDEX ON :Uri(uri)")
graph.run("CREATE INDEX ON :HTTP(uid)")
```

Maybe someone can give me hint what I am doing wrong or where I made mistakes in the code? 
The amount of commits comes due to transient errors while trying to write to neo4j. With a higher number of transactions, I had no more errors.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Have you created some schema constraints / indexes ?

Comment: I have added the contraints and indexes to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what py2neo is doing under the hood, from my experiences the python driver(s) are not the fastest ones.

I would probably go with plain Cypher statements where you have full control over what happens.

You also have some wrong/missing indexes, please check that all your queries / operations use an index. Those will otherwise result in full scans.

- (d:DNS {uid:{uid}})
- (d:HTTP {uid:{uid}})

I also suggest that you send a bit more data per transaction (like 10k records)

It also might to make sense to do some pre-processing per log-batch, e.g. create the distinct ip-nodes upfront per log-segment and not with each log-line.

this might help you too:
http://jexp.de/blog/2017/03/5-tips-tricks-for-fast-batched-updates-of-graph-structures-with-neo4j-and-cypher/

Comment: Thanks for the tips. As for the missing indexes. I have mismatched the code a little. The HTTP_Record and DNS_Record Indexes belong to the HTTP and DNS nodes from the code and have now the correct name.